# How to change Permalink by custom post type

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I want to change permalink by following way. Please suggest me the best solution.

www.domain.com/gallery/image.png  to www.domain.com/india/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a plugin.

Try this plugin:

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: its created like www.domain.com/india/gallery/image.png by using this one.